# Function not returning variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to detect the width of an image that I have the URL for:

```
var getWidth = function( url ){
    var i = new Image;
    i.onload = function(){
        var width = (this.width);
        alert( width );  // width defined here
        return width;
     }
     i.src = url;
}
var theWidth = getWidth( url ); 
alert( theWidth );  // undefined here
```

I need the width before I load the image so I can modify its container. I feel like there's an obvious solution here, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any jQuery?

Comment: you can't return from an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't return from an asynchronous callback. think about it. Doesn't this look a bit weird?

```
function foo () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        return "Hello World!";
    },2000)
}
alert(foo()); // undefined
```

The function will return undefined because it finishes before the timeout does. To solve this, have the function accept a callback that gets executed with the desired value.

```
function foo(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback("Hello World!");
    },2000)
}
foo(function(msg){
    alert(msg); // Hello World!
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that, but it makes sense they way you explained it. I got my code to work by modifying the image container from inside of the function.